# Shortcut to setting Variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There's a shortcut to this without having to specify SET all the time right?

So I thought you could combine declaration and assignment like this:

```
DECLARE @Field1 = 24.00,
        @Field2 = 11.10,
        @Field3  decimal = .50
```

am I doing this wrong or is it not possible and I must declare the variable and then use SET on every other line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 this should work:

```
DECLARE @Field1 decimal = 24.00,
        @Field2 decimal = 11.10,
        @Field3  decimal = .50
```

Looks like you just left out the type for the first two variables.

Comment: @KenWhite: If that is of any consolation, you would likely have been quicker than me. :)

Comment: actually I posted a bad example, typo.  The main problem was I was missing an = in ONE of my lines.  So it was stupid, I had like @Field int 10 and missed the =